# PDFParser not parsing pdf file and showing pdf as text file

Tags: php, pdf

I need to read pdf file content so I am using `PDFparser` library. I have `PDFparser` installed on my localhost `http://localhost/working-directory/Smalot/PdfParser`. I have `PDF` file in same working directory as well so I am using below code

```
<?php

include '/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php';
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('185.pdf');  
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;//all text from 185.pdf

$details  = $pdf->getDetails();
echo $details;

?>
```

to check output. Not `$text` or `$details` showing me anything and I also check length of both variables which comes zero. Does anyone know where is the problem please?
I tried to convert this `185.pdf` file on `PDFparser` directory itself and it was working fine but its not working at home.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

PDFParser is built on top of TCPDF parser.

Prerequisites

This library requires PHP 5.3.
PDFParser is built on top of TCPDF parser.
This library will be automatically downloaded through Composer command line.

In your json and also use only once

```
"require": {
    "smalot/pdfparser": "*"
}
```

just like that

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "~6.0",
    "smalot/pdfparser": "*"
},
```